What is the invariant volume form in a surface of Minkowski space
I'm reading Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians (001) and
ran into a problem.
In p379,
$V=\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$,
$V_{space}=\lbrace v\in V\vert v^2<0\rbrace$,
$\overline V$ is closure of $V$,
$ \lbrace e_1,...e_d \rbrace $ : standard basis ($\vert e_1\vert=1, \vert e_j\vert =-1$ (for $j=2,...,d$))
$V_+$ is one of connected component of $V- \overline V_{space} $ including $e_1$
For $m\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal O_{m}^+ = \lbrace v\in \overline {V_+} \vert v^2 =m^2, v\neq0\rbrace$.
And the author said

Let $dv$ be standard measure on $V$ and $\mu_m=Res\vert_{\mathcal O^+_m}\frac{dv}{v^2-m^2}$ be the invariant volume form on $\mathcal O_m^+$.

I think $dv$ means $e^1 \wedge e^2\wedge ... \wedge e^d$ (here $\lbrace e^j \rbrace$ is dual basis of $\lbrace e_j\rbrace$) but I'm not sure what "$Res\vert_{\mathcal O^+_m}\frac{dv}{v^2-m^2}$" and the meaning of "invariant" are.
Especially, the denominator of $\mu_m$ is $0$ and if $Res\vert_{\mathcal O^+_m}$ means "restriction to $\mathcal O^+_m$", $\mu_m$ cant be form on $\mathcal O_m^+$ because $dv$ is $d$-form and $\mathcal O_m^+$ is $(d-1)$-form.
Could you give me any idea to understand $\mu_m$?
Thanks for reading.
